# How to access App class from any page in Windows phone 8.1 sliverlight application?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-8.1, windows-phone, win-phone-silverlight-8.1

I have define some properties at application level in windows phone 8.1 sliverlight. Now I want to get an object of app.xaml.cs from any page like we can get application class in android. Please let me know if anyone knows.

Answer (score 1):

If i'm not mistake the App class is static which means that you can call it in your page like this

```
App.MyProperty
```

Just make sure you make your properties `static`

If you have many things you want to access just create a new static class and add everything there, you'll it like I mentioned above

Comment: @ViralThakker although it's not an issue, I'd suggest you go with the second way I proposed. Personally as a practise I want to keep the App.cs file as 'clean' as possible and always create another class to store some values